# Is my following reasoning right or wrong?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have three function $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$ and $f_3(x)$ (All are positive functions). The product of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ is concave over $0<x<1$ while $f_3(x)$ is concave over $x_1<x<x_2$ where $0<x_1<1$ and $0<x_2<1$ and $x_2>x_1$. Can I say that the product of three functions $f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)f_3(x)$ is concave in $x_1<x<x_2$ (I am only interesting in maximizing $f(x)$) Can this function $f(x)$ has zero derivative in isolated locations in $x_1<x<x_2$? In my view the set over which the function has zero derivative should be convex since the product of positive functions has one maxima.

Comment: Take for example $x_1=0, x_2=1, f_1(x)=1-x^2, f_2(x)=f_3(x)=1-(2x-1)^2$, then $f(x)$ will have two inflection points in $(0,1)$ thus [not concave](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-x%5E2)+(1+-+(2x-1)%5E2)%5E2++for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1), and also an isolated local maximum in between.

Comment: @dxiv then it means that the following paper is wrong? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02874642

Comment: Sorry, that's behind a paywall, so I can't tell if or how it relates to the question you posted. If something is not clear about my (counter)example, however, that's something I can probably answer.

Comment: Actually, I am interested in finding the maximum value of $f(x)$ and in your example the derivative is zero at the peak only. So one point is at the peak only since we have to exclude the $0$ and $1$

Comment: You asked `Can this function f(x) has zero derivative in isolated locations`. The answer is yes, and my example showed such an isolated point where the derivative is zero (which happened to be a maximum). Now you seem to be asking a different question, which honestly I don't quite follow. Next time around, please post the *full* question in the main post, with all the necessary details, so as to avoid misunderstandings and wasted time.

Comment: @dxiv can you please tell me where is the second inflection point in your curve. I am assuming $0$ and $1$ are not included so I am unable to see the second point where the derivative changes sign. thank you.

Comment: [$\frac{-1}{32} f''(x)=(x-1)(15 x^3 - 5 x^2 - 5 x + 1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+(+(1-x%5E2)(1-(2x-1)%5E2)%5E2+)%27%27) and the cubic changes sign between $0, \frac{1}{2}, 1$ so it has a real root in each of $(0,\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2}, 1)\,$.

Comment: P.S. The example from my initial comment did not meet the requirement for $f_1 \cdot f_2$ to be concave. Corrected in the posted answer, which does not otherwise change the rest of the points.

Answer (score 1):

The product need not be concave. Let $f_1=1$,$f_2(x)=1-x$ and $f_3(x)=1-x^{2}$. Then $f_1 f_2 f_3$ is concave on $(0,1/3)$ and convex on $(1/3,1)$.

Comment: From $-1$ to $1$ the function is concave while it is decreasing function for $(0,1)$

Comment: for $x>1$ the function becomes negative

Comment: Frank Moses, as I understand the whole problem is restricted to (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

The product is not necessarily concave, and can have an isolated local extremum.

Take for example $x_1 = 0, \,x_2 = 1, \,f_1(x) = 1+x−x^2 ,f_2(x) = f_3(x) = 1−(2x−1)^2\,$, then:

- each of [$f_1\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx-x%5E2)+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1), [$f_2\,$, $f_3\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+(2x-1)%5E2+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1) is positive and concave on $(0,1)\,$
- [$f_1 \cdot f_2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx-x%5E2)(1-(2x-1)%5E2)%20for%200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%201) is also concave on $(0,1)$
- [$f = f_1 \cdot f_2 \cdot f_3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx-x%5E2)(1-(2x-1)%5E2)%5E2%20for%200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%201)  is *not* concave on $(0,1)\,$, in fact it changes concavity twice
- $f'$ has an isolated $0$ on $(0,1)$ which corresponds to a local maximum of $f$

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "changes concavity twice"? Do you mean that the derivative changes sign more than once in the interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: the derivative changes sign just once. So when the derivative is equal to zero we can find the maxima value

Comment: Also I am interested in the interval where the functions are defined to be concave. I wanted to see whether in that region there can be isolated peaks. However, your answers and comments has helped me in understanding more deeply. So thanks for your help

Comment: @FrankMoses `What do you mean by "changes concavity twice"?` It is convex, then concave, then convex again on $(0,1)$. `the derivative changes sign more than once?` No, the $2^{nd}$ derivative has two zeros, corresponding to the inflection points. The $1^{st}$ derivative doesn't (necessarily) change sign at inflection points.

Comment: well to find the maxima I think I will be needing the first derivative. Right?

Comment: @FrankMoses Right, the local extrema correspond to zeros of the first derivative, not the $\color{red}{2^{nd}}$ derivative.