# Where is the following reasoning wrong?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have read in following paper "OPTIMIZATION FOR PRODUCTS OF CONCAVE FUNCTIONS" that if $f_1(x)$ $f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x)$ are positive concave functions in some interval $[a,b]$ then their product $h(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x)$ has following property. 
[image]

1- There exist points $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $a\leq \alpha \leq\beta\leq b$ such that $h$ is strictly increasing on $[a,\alpha)$, constant on $(\alpha,\beta)$ and strictly decreasing on $(\beta,b]$.

In my thinking this means that $h(x)$ can not have isolated maxima in $[a,b]$ (due to the conditions described for the derivative). However I have seen some examples where the function can have more than one maxima and the sign of the derivative also changes more than once. Can anybody please explain me where I am wrong in understanding this.

Comment: can you state one example that you have seen?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh here is one example http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-x%5E2)+(1+-+(2x-1)%5E2)%5E2++for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh the other example is when $h(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)f_3(x)$ where $f_1(x)=1, f_2(x)=1-x$ and $f_3(x)=1-x^2$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: @FrankMoses Guess this explains your previous [couple of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572740/is-my-following-reasoning-right-or-wrong) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572665/product-of-decreasing-function-and-concave-function). That's what you should have posted, instead, to begin with.

Comment: @dxiv I am sorry but I do not understand. In my thinking either the paper (from which I have taken image) is wrong

Answer (score 3):

The first function first increases up to the unique global maximum on $[0,1]$ and then it decreases. It does not have multiple maxima that are isolated.

[image]

For the second example $h(x)=(1-x)(1-x^2)$, the unique global maximum on $[0,1]$ is $0$ and it is a decreasing function on $[0,1]$.[image]

Edit: I have included the graph of the first function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is how it can have zero derivative at two different isolated locations? The image of the paper that I have attached does not allow it to have zero derivative at two different isolated locations. Can you comment on that?

Comment: which point of the image are you referring to?

Comment: the image in my question.Point two of the question where it describe the strictly increasing and strictly decreasing behaviour

Comment: The functions that are shown indeed increases, then potentially stay constant and drop right? It is ok to have global minimum at the boundary, no rules is against that isn't it.

Comment: No your first image (with blue color) has a derivative which changes sign more than once. But the paper image that I attached in my question says that for a certain domain the derivative is positive and for a certain domain it is negative otherwise it is zero. So it can change sign only once

Comment: i mean after achieving the maximum it has changed sign right? Now it can no longer change its sign according to the point 2 of my image

Comment: I have included the graph of the derivative, it changes sign exactly once on $[0,1]$.

Comment: If you plot it from $(-2,1)$ then you can see that the derivative changes sign more than once

Comment: The theorem only promises what happens on a particular interval, in this case, it is $[0,1]$.  It doesn't promise behavior of the function outside the interval. $1-x^2$ is not always nonnegative on $(-2,1)$.